# impersonal authentication The user name or password is incorrect

Tags: c#, authentication, impersonation

I'm trying to use the impersonal authentication on my C# project but I'm getting the following error:
"The user name or password is incorrect."
My code is:

```
string domain = "";
string user = "Administrator";
string pwd = "myPassword";
ICryptoManager objCM = new CryptoManager();
objCM.LogonUser(domain, user, pwd, Missing.Value);
```

User and password are correct for sure, so I think the domain isn't, but I don't know what value I have to set. I tried ".\", ".", "local" but no one is coorect.
My server is a Windows Server 2016.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: What's the implementation for `CryptoManager.LogonUser`? I don't think it's a framework class, is it?

Comment: Is a class of a library that could be downloadaded from http://www.aspencrypt.com/

Comment: @Pimager did you come up with a solution?